# Difference between text and string in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I search for tags which contain specific text in BeautifulSoup, I use `find_all(string='text I want')`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<a id="someid">stackoverflow</a>', 'lxml')
soup.find_all(string='stackoverflow')
```

But I recently found that I can do so by

```
soup.find_all(text='stackoverflow')
```

I went over the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for BeautifulSoup 4, but I couldn't find any clue on find_all with text argument.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument):

> With string you can search for strings instead of tags.
>   The string argument is new in Beautiful Soup 4.4.0. In earlier versions it was called text.